# REST - Creating session

Tags: spring, spring-security

I write application which use Spring Security. Below I wrote my TokenFilter and WebSecurityConfig. 
My question is how long SecurityContext does contain logged users?
Next question: is my security configuration session stateless or no? Is SecurityContext replacment for Session?

Does my application fulfill the stateless principle?

```
public class TokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private TokenHelper tokenHelper;

    private String tokenHeader = "Auth";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authToken = httpServletRequest.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);

        final String username = tokenHelper.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            final UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (tokenHelper.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

And Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Autowired
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public TokenFilter tokenFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(
                tokenFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
        );

        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SecurityContext` is only used to access `Authentication` instance.

`SecurityContext` may be stored between your requests. This logic (storing and then restoring for new requests) is implemented in `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` which, in turn, delegates this storage logic to `SecurityContextRepository`.

When you use `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`, `NullSecurityContextRepository` is used (it is an implementation of `SecurityContextRepository`); it does NOT actually store `SecurityContext` anywhere, and it always 'restores' a fresh (empty) `SecurityContext`.

`SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` also forbids Spring Security to create http session in any of beans which form its machinery.

So when you use `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`, the session is never created, and it is certainly not used to store `SecurityContext`. Each your request will have a fresh security context (with no `Authentication` in it), so each your request will perform a full-blown authentication.

Comment: After I validate the token, I embed user into SecurityContext. So, I do not need to try deleting the user from SecurityContext as performing logout operation since it is not really there. After the request completion, the user and SecurityContext for that thread would be gone. Am I understood right?